# How to call a REST Api using Rest Template with Bearer Token and form-data in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, oauth

I am calling a rest api using Postman and it gives a successful response (200 OK) using following request,

method: POST

Authorization =>
Type: Bearer Token =>
Token: saflsjdflj

Body =>
form-data =>
Key: companyId,
Value: 123456

But when I call this api in spring boot using rest template it gives 400 bad request. The code is shown below,

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

HashMap<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
requestBody.put("companyId", "123456");

HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers)

ResponseEntity<CompanyResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, CompanyResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure restTemplate: add FormHttpMessageConverter

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .messageConverters(
                        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()),
                        new FormHttpMessageConverter())
                .build()
```

And when sending request, you have to set `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` as contentType and use `MultiValueMap` instead of `HashMap` as request body:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
requestBody.put("companyId", "123456");

HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers)

ResponseEntity<CompanyResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, CompanyResponse.class);
```

Comment: I think that now there is some issue with response class. Could you show it (response class)?

Comment: thanks it worked, my response pojo class was not properly constructed.